# Highlight one column in highchart-vue on mounted hook

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I am new to both vue and highchart.
What I need to do is I need to highlight (jun) column to highlight with custom color.
I found the answer in jquery way.
[solution for jquery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823900/highlight-single-bar-column-in-highcharts-on-load)

But I don't know how to do this in vue.

Here is [Code Sandbox link!](https://codesandbox.io/s/highchart-iinzv?file=/src/components/ColumnChart.vue)

I used [highchart-vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue)

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: Hi @mg-kh, Maybe the `selected` option will be enough for you? Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highchart-forked-8coo8

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you Sir! It is what i need to fix my problem. :)